# How to get the remaining hours between the current date and a date in a millisecond format in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs to display a list of items in jsonArray. and i want to compute the remaining hours so i think that in order to solve that i need to subtract the current date with the date from the jsonArray which is the **purchaseTime**. The output should be like this format: **12 Hrs**

Script

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('orderCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
$scope.orders = ${orderList.raw()};
});
```

jsonArray item

```
"purchaseTime": "1449576000000"
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="orderCtrl">
<div class="divs" ng-repeat="order in orders| orderBy: '+purchaseTime'">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><p>{{$index + 1}}</p></li>
            <li><p>{{(Date.now() - order.purchaseTime) | date:"h"}}</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think that I am not getting the right remaining time. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I would advise momentjs!

Comment: So based on my answer below, I think you should not use the date filter for this purpose, but instead simply Use your current expression and divide the result by 1000 to get seconds, then divide again by 60 to get minutes and again by 60 to get hours. So you end up with something like...

Comment: So based on my answer below, I think you should not use the date filter for this purpose, but instead simply Use your current expression and divide the result by 1000 to get seconds, then divide again by 60 to get minutes and again by 60 to get hours. So you end up with something like...`<li><p>{{Math.round((Date.now() - order.purchaseTime)/1000)/60/60}} Hrs</p></li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom directive for that purpose:

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("orderCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.orders = [{id:1,"purchaseTime": "1449651824588"},{id:2,"purchaseTime": "1449665002689"}];
});

app.directive("calcTime", function($compile) {
    var timeDifference;
    var currentDate;
    var deadLine;
    var diffDays;
    var diffHours;
    var diffMinutes;
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        currentDate = new Date();
        deadLine = new Date(parseInt(attrs.calcTime)); // setting purchase time Date Object
        deadLine = new Date(deadLine.setDate(deadLine.getDate()+1)); // setting purchase time Date Object + 1 day
        timeDifference = (deadLine.getTime()) - (currentDate.getTime()); // deadline data minus current date
                var diffDays = Math.floor(timeDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
        var diffHours = Math.floor(timeDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60)); 
        var diffMinutes = Math.floor((timeDifference-(diffHours*(1000 * 60 * 60))) / (1000 * 60)); 

        element.html(diffDays + " days, " + diffHours + " hours and "+ diffMinutes +" minutes till DeadLine")
            }
    };  
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="orderCtrl">
<div class="divs" ng-repeat="order in orders| orderBy: '+purchaseTime'">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Purchase Time: {{order.purchaseTime | date:'MM/dd/yyyy - hh:mm'}}<p calc-time="{{order.purchaseTime}}"></p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

A working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fixit/v0daewLc/2/)

Comment: Hi sir, Good day! I tried your code and I think I am not getting the right result because I need to get the remaining time. The start time is the purchase time and the deadline is if you add 24 hours to the purchaseTime.

Comment: Hi Sir Yonatan Ayalon, it works fine for me, THANK you! you save me. :D GODbless.

Answer (score 0):

By using the Date object:

```
var a = new Date(); // Now
var b = new Date(2010, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); // 2010
var d = (b-a); // difference in milliseconds
```

You can get the number of seconds by dividing the milliseconds by 1000, and rounding the number:

```
var seconds = Math.round((b-a)/1000);
```

You could then get minutes by again dividing seconds by 60, then hours by dividing minutes by 60, then days by dividing hours by 24, etc.

You'll note that I provided some values for the second Date object. Those parameters are as follows:

```
// new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

You don't necessarily need to provide all of these values unless they're necessary for the date you wish to represent. Only the `month` and `year` are required, the rest are optional.